# Problems with file_exists() with metabox plugin in WordPress

Tags: plugins, metabox

I'm using metabox plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) and I get this warning message:

Warning: file_exists(): File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on this platform (4096): /usr/home/mydomain.com/web/BLOG/wp-content/plugins/meta-box/inc/905ai0evm8qpx-wsfhq1h72rml-zz614ijl0r7dot3brnnip1atfrlg-irkh4c278jlcq7f7dr8pfnvu5ac-qrevqqoqf6dm9i7-h14oga5j3nvvqaga37-7lpoqz6cvqaha3321egkednip3ats1j2mgflkcijx95l3m16p6uyr752u6atysrl36uyr852u7atsh72vutg1cvfaqaka36fsv85kvbvvhaja30mrgix8fiiq905aizrwdih8c3i7wsm9fpcpkih8cri7xd6rh7d2t27tciorjbrwq7j03kj90z0qxv2-qh22erl9ymqw8xied13mkh1pa67jrtilmm7cv3zu23ot36koom2cl37s2skg53q-vvcz75-td3pvjmukh1d1sntgfomxbvo8m7m3wv1-f2m3r-5yshkottia0b0j8xied12ooz0z74ahc6lwnt2lj10p7yaoa6fccv7nws8zeeovt-lhptvomeh9b4xm1lruqhf2sdxc2iowi68wyhg-h1ma9b7tjgp0lja7sdc5mg6rcvph6vc0ptja2cxhk65-v-7wwe8ppjxjj-yey72xdp9xun3jietbrzai6ex9yc778sllizr8wpib287rhk53p0egti49y5vvqaglq7a7tejrulluhb5asr7sqgzt33wts8wsd4i-iq9h3l3whcqrhiivxih8cri7-twfu7dlt5h8csi7j-6w3y2iovr8c4i7x6joom6a6u5rwvja4sllizrsdlkbgoykfim3prektijex8zjqstamzn2t3ge-3vvqaciq76rqazaebprk-tbrzbi6a5e52vvqacmq76rqax9r-w9t-4xlurjwv in /usr/home/mydomain.com/web/BLOG/wp-content/plugins/meta-box/inc/autoloader.php on line 174

What can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to fix this. Shorten the file path. My suggestion is that you contact the plugin author and report this as a bug. I also suggest doing a security review of your site, because that looks somewhat suspicious to me. There's no good reason for a file path to be that long. It's either malicious, or a bug in code results in an unexpected file path formulation.